# Cocos2D Game Crashes in Old Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, memory-warning

I developed a game in cocos2D.I used to build and run the game in my Old Ipad as well as in my new Ipad2(both updated to IOS 5.0).In GDB it shows memory warning level1 and automatically freed unused sprites and spritesheets.**Due to this my game crashes in Old Ipad but runs very fine in my new Ipad2**.What is the problem with my old Ipad???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your "old" iPad 1 has 256 MB of memory. The iPad 2 has 512 MB.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPad)

From that and "memory warning level1" I think it's pretty obvious what the problem is.

The solution is to use less memory, at least on iPad 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem per se - your old iPad just has less memory than your new one :)

You need to use less memory (or free more memory when you receive a memory warning!)